# Heroku dependency installation failed. Composer installation failed with an error

Tags: laravel, heroku, git-push

I am deploying my app on heroku for the first time and it failed to push on the heroku platform.
[image]

This is my composer.json
[image]
[image]
This is the code on my procfile

web:vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/

Comment: please no images of code

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the
> laravel/ui package.

You need to install `laravel/ui` into your app:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```